# Parse last part of string with certain requirements in R

Tags: regex, r

I want to subset a data frame on the last part of a string but my regex skills in R are lacking. Here is the problem im running into. I have a column that looks like this:

```
EM1234 > COMJ1234 > ADW1234
ADW1234 > COMJ1234 > EM1234
EM4321 > COMJ1234 > EM1234
COMJEM > ADW1234 > MSNK123
COMJ12 > ADW1234 > EMP1234
```

I only want to subset data that ENDS with EM and not EMP. I also run into the last problem with the first COMJEM. As using regex for any character would include that example. Here is what I am currently using but does not work:

```
sources <- data.frame(column = I(c('EM1234 > COMJ1234 > ADW1234',
                                   'ADW1234 > COMJ1234 > EM1234',
                                   'EM4321 > COMJ1234 > EM1234',
                                   'COMJEM > ADW1234 > MSNK123',
                                   'COMJ12 > ADW1234 > EMP1234')))
subset <- sources[grep("^'.+EM[[:alnum:]]{2,8}'$", sources$column),]
```

What is a better way to write this regex? The answer should result subsetting to look like this:

```
ADW1234 > COMJ1234> EM1234
EM4321 > COMJ1234> EM1234
```

Comment: Try this expression string `"^.+EM\\d{2,8}$"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a word boundary `\b` and match at the end of the string:

```
sources[grep('\\bEM[^P]\\S+$', sources$column),]
# [1] "ADW1234 > COMJ1234 > EM1234" "EM4321 > COMJ1234 > EM1234"
```

Comment: Sweet! this worked! Thanks so much. It was still inclusive of things ending in COMJEM* but I was able do subset out using your example. I just added this and got what I wanted:                                                    no.COMJ <- sources[!grepl('COMJEM[^P ]*$', sources$column),]

Comment: @DanielConnell, you don't need to do that, the updated answer will exclude those.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `\\d` or `[:digit:]`, since `[:alnum:]` matches all alphanumeric characters (i.e. `[:alpha:]` and `[:digit:]`).   Also I think you want to drop the single quotes in your string, as in:

```
"^.+EM\\d{2,8}$"
```

or

```
"^.+EM[[:digit:]]{2,8}$"
```

Comment: Thanks Jthorpe - I guess I should have provided a better example as I do have some that end in COMJEM* , so this would be inclusive. Also I used [:alnum:] because there are also letters that suffix the EM sometimes.